# Jquery remove records from database but table row not fadeout

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using this code in Codeigniter framework, Following code delete record from database, but table row not removed or fadeout... please check code, and let me know, how to fix this code..

**HTML Code:**

```
<table id="tbl1">
 <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>admin/delete/<?php echo $get->id; ?>" class="deleteLink">Delete</a></td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".deleteLink").click(function(e){
            $this  = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.get(url, function(r){
                if(r.success){
                    $this.closest("tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
});
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public function delete($id){

        if (!$id) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $delete = $this->db->delete($this->_table_name);
            if ( $delete ) return json_encode(array("success" => true));
}
```

Comment: and what do you return from controller in case of success?

Comment: check controller code, json_encode

Comment: so after adding success response, it still doesn't work?

Comment: yes, record deleted, but row still visible in form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your controller doesn't really return any data as ajax, right? A solution would be:

```
public function delete($id) {

    $result = array('success' => FALSE, 'error' => '');

    if (!$id) {
        echo json_encode($result);
    }

    $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    // if row was deleted successfully, result in success
    if( $this->db->delete($this->_table_name) !== FALSE) {
        $result['success'] = TRUE;

    // otherwise result in error!
    }else{
        $result['success'] = FALSE;
        $result['error'] = 'Row could not be deleted!';
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

You then would have a JSON object as AJAX response, that you could easily access to in your GET callback:

```
$.get(url, function(r){
    if(r.success){
        $this.closest("tr").remove();
    }else{
        alert('An error occured: ' + r.error);
    }
}, 'json');
```

Please notice the `'}, 'json');` part - that tells your GET() function, that your result is in JSON format.

Comment: Still record deleted from database, no alert, no fadeout

Comment: What's the console output of your get response?
`console.log(r)`

Comment: i checked in firebug, its show error 'Uh oh!', but record deleted

Comment: Noticed an error in my code arround the `if` part of the controller. Try now and tell us, if `console.log(r.success)` results in true. Otherwise check the output of your database model's delete function.

Comment: Great, i fixed controller code, and its working... please let me know, how i fadeout row?

Comment: @user1218948 $this.closest("tr").fadeOut();

Comment: Try `$this.closest('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).remove(); });`
This will first fade out the row and remove it afterwards